# Sharing startup objects

Tags: playframework, elasticsearch, playframework-1.x

I'm trying to create an Elasticsearch node client on application startup (It's a slow process to do on every request)

I know I can use Jobs to create the connection but I'm not sure how to share this with methods in the controller of the application?

I'm using play 1.2.7

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you create the client?

Comment: Maybe you can initialize the elasticsearch connection in any class and then re-use it from either the Controller or Job, depending if your searches take a long time or not. A static initializer might be useful for that. If you want to use a job, I guess the Application startup annotation can be used for that.